# Input value in textbox to add in another textbox

Tags: javascript, html

When I enter an amount in the input box it should add to value of item stocks, then if I remove my entered amount stocks should go back to its original stocks/previous stocks.

how can I achieve this?

Note : Value of item stocks is a value on my DB. I make a query and echo it as value in an input box.

this is the Html :

```
<input type="text" id="Stocks" class="form-control input-text qty text"  value="<?php echo A3_Stocks();?>"/>
<input type="text" id="addNum" title="Enter Amount to Add in Stocks" class="form-control input-text qty text tip-bottom"/>
```

this is what I've tried (it does add, but it's not accurate, and shows NaN when amount entered is removed) :

```
$('#addNum').on('keyup', function() {
    var input2  = parseInt($('#Stocks').val()); // stocks
    var input1   = parseInt($(this).val()); // add num
    input2 = input1 + input2;
    $("#Stocks").val(input2);
});
```

Comment: You could use the *logical OR* operator .... `parseInt( value || 0)` to account for empty values

Comment: @charlietfl okay, now how to make the stocks go back to it's previous value when amount entered removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var originalValue;

queryStockValue().then(function(response){
   originalValue = response.data;
});

$('#addNum').on('keyup', function() {
    var input2  = parseInt($('#Stocks').val());
    var input1   = parseInt($(this).val());
    input2 = isNaN(input1)? originalValue : (input1 + input2);
    $("#Stocks").val(input2);
});
```